# FirebaseUI Android: Error fetching providers for email (Backend Error)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

We use Firebase and FirebaseUI-Auth with email accounts in one of our Android apps.

When we try to log in using FirebaseUI-Auth with a specific email account, the progress dialog (`progress_dialog_checking_accounts`) hides without showing an error and what we see in logcat is the following:

```
W/CheckEmailFragment: Error fetching providers for email
    com.google.firebase.c: An internal error has occurred. [ Backend Error ]
    at com.google.android.gms.c.eg.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.c.ed$f.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.c.eo.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.c.eo$a.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.c.ej$a.onTransact(Unknown Source)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453)
```

The results of the following curl request are not very informative either:

```
curl 'https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/createAuthUri?key=${MyFirebaseAPIKey}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-binary '{"identifier": "${ProblematicEmailAddress}","continueUri":"http://localhost"}'
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "backendError",
    "message": "Backend Error"
   }
  ],
  "code": 500,
  "message": "Backend Error"
 }
}
```

I get a good response with another email address (also a registered account):

```
{
 "kind": "identitytoolkit#CreateAuthUriResponse",
 "allProviders": [
  "password"
 ],
 "registered": true,
 "sessionId": "${replaced}"
}
```

Does anyone know what is happening and how we can solve this error? We are concerned, that this might occur for other email accounts as well, thus preventing users from signing in.

Comment: have you check before login that is user email exist in Authentication table of firebase?
URL like : https://console.firebase.google.com/project/[Project-Id]/authentication/users

Comment: Yes. This users email is shown in the Firebase authentication user table.

Comment: I think you have not enable email sign in method . So goto->Sign in method-> Enable email/password

Comment: Of course I have enabled email sign in. It works with lots of email accounts already.

Comment: Can you provide the full backend error for that request? If not can you call this API: curl 'https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/createAuthUri?key=[API_KEY]' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-binary '{"identifier":"[user@example.com]","continueUri":"http://localhost"}' Substitute your API key and email and provide us with the full error.

Comment: @bojeil thanks for your help, I have updated the question with the results I got.

Comment: I think you need to contact Firebase support and give them the API key and problematic email in order to resolve this.

Comment: @bojeil You were right. This was a problem only Firebase support was able to help us with. They had to forward it to engineers to fix it.